# compare date in aspx(html) page?

Tags: c#-4.0, datetime, asp.net-4.0

I am trying to compare current date with a date. I wrote below part but i get error

as    ) expected and am i allowed to compare in below format?

```
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("PDate")) > DateTime.Now ? Eval("PDate","{0:dd-MMM-yy}"):Publish Soon %>'></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the parenthesis, it looks like you need a closing `)` for the second `Eval`.

Is there a reason you don't set `Label4.Text` in the code-behind? It will make your life easier.

Comment: i know we can do it in code-behind but i am just trying to get it done in html side and about the paraenthesis  i don't think your's is correct format. i wanted to display "Publish soon" if false.

Comment: ok i realized i can't write "Publish Soon". It says it doesn't exist. I thought i could write any text. about the paraenthesis when i write 'null' it works. Like below.Text='<%#Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("PDate")) > DateTime.Now ? Eval("PDate","{0:dd-MMM-yy}"):null %>'>